# get data from a querystring

Tags: vb.net, query-string, pageload

i have this querystring that shall open up my page.
http://www.a1-one.com/newpage.aspx?email=er@old.com&stuid=123456

Now when this page loads, on page_load, I want to pick up email and stuid in two different variables. So I can use them to insert into my database (sql server)
how can this be done in vb.net

Answer (score 7):

Use `Request.QueryString("email")` and `Request.QueryString("stuid")`.